# Is std::vector memory freed upon a clear?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, vector

Suppose I have a std::vector of structs. What happens to the memory if the vector is clear()'d?

```
std::vector<myStruct> vecs;
vecs.resize(10000);
vecs.clear();
```

Will the memory be freed, or still attached to the vecs variable as a reusable buffer?

Comment: Thanks everyone. I want the memory to be freed - guaranteed. So I allocate the vector using new std:vector<myStruct>, then call delete when I'm done. Thus memory guaranteed to be freed.

Comment: @AndrewS.: the only effect of the dynamic allocation is to introduce an ineffiency. see jerry's answer for a reasonable way to empty a vector. in a loop body another good way is to just make the vector local to the loop body, i.e. declare it inside the loop body.

Comment: Just for interest, why does the memory need to be guaranteed free?

Comment: Because this is ios operation and I am trying to be economical with memory on the more limited platform.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The memory remains attached to the vector. That isn't just likely either. It's required. In particular, if you were to add elements to the vector again after calling `clear()`, the vector must not reallocate until you add more elements than the 10000 as it was previously sized.

If you want to free the memory, the usual is to swap with an empty vector. C++11 also adds a [`shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) member function that's intended to provide roughly the same capability more directly, but it's non-binding (in other words, it's likely to release extra memory, but still not truly required to do so).

Comment: For me it does not work. I have a vector of structure and an image is a element of structure. By doing `shrink_to_fit` it does not release GPU or RAM.

Answer (score 39):

The vector's memory is not guaranteed to be cleared. You cannot safely access the elements after a clear. To make sure the memory is deallocated Scott Meyers advised to do this:

```
vector<myStruct>().swap( vecs );
```

[Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) has the following to say on this:

> Removes all elements from the vector, calling their respective
>   destructors, leaving the container with a size of 0.
>
> The vector capacity does not change, and no reallocations happen due
>   to calling this function. A typical alternative that forces a
>   reallocation is to use swap:...

Comment: Is it not guaranteed to be cleared? Or guaranteed not to be cleared? Those are two very different things!

Comment: Yep it's guaranteed to be not cleared. Answer is misleading

Answer (score 10):

The destructor is called on the objects, but the memory remains allocated.

Answer (score 7):

No, memory are not freed.

In C++11, you can use the `shrink_to_fit` method for force the vector to free memory.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: You can use it, but the standard specifies that it does *not* force extra memory to be released (§23.3.6.3/6): "shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size()."

Comment: ... and thus, it's about as good as `resize(0)` which *might* have the side effect of releasing the memory

Comment: No, `resize(0)` is [guaranteed to keep the memory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).

Comment: resize(0) has better not have that side effect! What a terrible decision it would be leaving that up to chance.

Answer (score 6):

`.resize(0)` and `.clear()` don't release or reallocate allocated memory, they just resize vector to zero size, leaving capacity same.

If we need to clear with freeing (releasing) memory following works:

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/frbedd1fd)

```
v = std::vector<T>();
```

It calls `&&` overload of `=` operator, which does moving, similar behaviour as with `swap()` solution.

This assignment technique works when there is `&&` overload of `=` operator, and it'is guaranteed to be present in all C++11 STD libraries, [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D). So if you compile with `-std=c++11` (gcc/clang) or `/std:c++11` (msvc) switch (or later) my solution is guaranteed to work.

Comment: but the question is really _is it **required** to?_ not just does it happen to with this code, compiler, settings, etc. why would Meyers et al recommend `swap()` if assigning would suffice?

Comment: @underscore_d Yes, my assigning code clears and releases memory always with recent compilers. Probably Meyers used `swap()` because his book was quite old, when there was no `&&` rvalue reference. Because my assignment wouldn't work when there is no `&&` overload of `=` operator, and this overload presents already everywhere in all STD libraries for quite many last years. `&&` is guaranteed to be present in all C++11 STD libraries, [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

Comment: This is so far the most modern answer. The point is that `std::vector<T>()` returns a temporary object, which is swapped with the content of `v` and then immediately reaches the end of its life.