# How to avoid reinitializing a vector every time though an openmp for loop?

Tags: c++, openmp, hpc

I have a for loop that looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    vector<double> vec;
    //then do work on vec, such as resize or push_back
}
```

This is inefficient because every time through the loop, vec is resized, and this may force a dynamic memory allocation every time through the for loop. So an easy optimization is:

```
vector<double> vec;
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    vec.clear();
    //then do work on vec, such as resize or push_back
}
```

This is faster because clear does not deallocate the memory in vec, and so we don't have to deallocate and reallocate the memory every time.

But what if I want to parallelize the for loop with openmp? I can't have all the threads share that one vector 'vec'. So seems like I need to go back to the first option and reinitialize the vector every time through the loop, like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    vector<double> vec;
    //then do work on vec, such as resize or push_back
}
```

Is there a way to avoid this inefficiency and avoid reallocating the vector every time? Would it be safe to do something like this?

```
vector<vector<double>> outervec;
outervec.resize(omp_get_max_threads());

#pragma omp parallel for shared(outervec)
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    vector<double> &vec = outervec[tid];
    vec.clear();
    //then do work on vec, such as resize or push_back
}
```

When vec is resized, it might become quite large, and the number of times through the for loop N might be large as well. Allocating memory in vectors is slow when it is done many times for large chunks of memory. The idea is to try to avoid having to deallocate and then reallocate the dynamically allocating memory stored in vec every time. The concern is not the stack allocated memory footprint of the vector object (which is small and quickly allocated), but the heap allocated memory that belongs to the vector object.

Comment: Either you want each thread to use its own vector, or not. If yes, than the vector needs to be created per thread, and it seems to be whether all the vectors get created before the threads get created, or whether each thread creates its own vector, the amount of work is logically the same, and would actually benefit from parallelization.

Comment: Each thread has its own stack, so however you try it (using e.g. thread_local) you will have a new vector.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis - I edited the question to add a shared(outervec), so now the vector of vectors is explicitly shared among the threads. Anyway, I am not sure if this is the right solution - am looking for a suggestion.

Comment: I mean listen: take a look at this: https://godbolt.org/z/Whv63o
now change the code to be a local variable. Simpler assembly and probably faster. Also you made the assumption that clear will not deallocate and reallocate, not sure why. Always go for simpler code unless profiling shows a bottleneck, then it's okay to do tricks and hacks. Compilers are relatively smart.

To answer your question, the outervec trick should work fine. Don't recommend it though.

Comment: Also consider doing it the C way. Use a fixed size buffer with the maximum number of elements you expect. This way you could avoid dynamic allocations altogether.

Comment: @AdamZahran Calling clear() on a vector does not decallocate the memory: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944886/is-stdvector-memory-freed-upon-a-clear

Comment: @AdamZahran Using a fixed size buffer is not an acceptable approach because I don't know in advance the maximum size, and it might be large.

Comment: modifying elements or resizing the vector are very different things. if you can approximate(up) the size of the vector before the loop starts you can size the vector accordingly and modify its elements in parallel.

Comment: based on your comment, you can use a vector built for parallelism. intel tbb or the windows ppl offer such types.

Comment: @Adam An Intel TBB vector is probably overkill. That's a more complicated data structure, would need to change compiler, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually very simple. `#pragma omp parallel for` is a compound statement - you can split that:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    std::vector<double> vec;
    #pragma omp for
    for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
        vec.clear();
        //then do work on vec, such as resize or push_back
    }
}
```

This will work just fine as you expect.

This is a clear case, where the "clean" solution of initializing the vector for each loop has performance penalty that will often enough be relevant..

Sometimes you might want to use the `#pragma omp threadprivate` directive, if this "cache"-vector is a global / static variable.

Your suggested solution:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> outervec;
outervec.resize(omp_get_max_threads());

#pragma omp parallel for shared(outervec)
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    int tid = omp_get_thread_num();
    auto& vec = outervec[tid];
    vec.clear();
    //then do work on vec, such as resize or push_back
}
```

will work but has another huge performance issue. This will very likely introduce false-sharing - the pointers used by multiple `std::vector` instances are stored in the same cache line. If theses are modified frequently, i.e, with a `push_back`, performance will suffer. This could easily be worse than the "clean" solution.

If you must, for some reason, bring in the vector from the outside. Make private copies with `firstprivate`, i.e.:

```
std::vector<double> vec;
#pragma omp parallel for firstprivate(vec)
for (int i = 0;i<N;i++) {
    vec.clear();
    //then do work on vec, such as resize or push_back
}
```

Don't use `private(vec)` as it leaves the variables uninitialized, and `vec.clear()` would explode.

Comment: Thanks! This makes complete sense.